# Big data api to fetch async without server memory issue & manual modifications

Tags: php, mysql, api, asynchronous, bigdata

I have a big data API ( 500000 records ) each record has big data in JSON format. I write code to read that API and store that data in the desired format in the MySql table, then I have to put that data to another API so I coded to send data in JSON format to other API, everything works well. The issue is server goes out of memory or 500 error after 100 records only and I have to check my database again for what the last id inserted there and then update code manually each time to get that API execution again.

My Question is how can we continuously add very big data without server outrages or any error may be Async mode or something else, I don't need to check manually each time after 100 records. I am using the latest version of PHP, MySql, Digital Ocean VPN server.  Data is very big and it needs to be updated daily so it is not possible for me to keep looking at this part daily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not sound like something you should do with PHP

Comment: it depends a lot on your code and it should be examined, but I think as a temporary solution you can break this operation into smaller operations that only process 100 records.

Comment: Yes, I know nothing to do with PHP. For details I shared what tools I used.

Comment: It would be better to share the details that matter, like: do you have any specific problem with updating the data? How do you do it currently? What's the **exact** error message you are facing?

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei thanks for your comment, I already tried that as well but the server goes hang up or throws 500 error after 100 records so the script stops working and I have to go to MySQL to check what the last id there, and then I restart API from that ip.

Comment: @YuvrajJain so we can't help without any specific error, code or log

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei I am getting error something like this when I try to fetch 100+ records.

Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 126976 bytes) in

Comment: Then why not share your code, such that others could check it for problems? 2 MB of allowed memory size are... pretty strange

Comment: @NicoHaase :- It is simple code nothing new just pulling data from API and sending it to MySQL and back to other API all data in JSON.

Comment: If such "simple code" triggers a memory limit, which is set at 2 MB, it should get optimized

Comment: What is the typical JSON size?  Which thing is running out of memory?  What SQL is used to "store" the data in MySQL?

Comment: Are you using Apache?  What does it's error log show?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Is one JSON bigger than the 2MB that you exhausted?  Have you tried raising the memory limit in PHP?